# Entity Framework: no Primary key/can't execute Stored Procedures

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, stored-procedures, primary-key

I have a database with Stored procedures, and i used Ado.Net Entity Data Modell and Ado.Net DBContext generator. After this part i've got error: "no primery key". 
I modify in .edmx file in entityset line: store.schema="dbo" to schema="dbo" and remove .... 
This way works the update rows, but Stored Procedures doesn't execute.

Example:
After Edit is working, i've insert this line to edit:

```
db.SetChangedByUserTrue(id);
```

So my controller is:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, ProductResource blog)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new OnlineCAT_Maint_TESTEntities())
            {
                db.Entry(blog).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                db.SetChangedByUserTrue(id);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

My SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SetChangedByUserTrue
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ProductResourceId int

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    update OnlineCAT_Maint_TEST.dbo.ProductResource set ChangedByUser = 1 where ProductResourceId = @ProductResourceId
END
```

And this is the error:

> {"Invalid object name 'OnlineCAT_Maint_TEST.dbo.ProductResource'."}

Connection between two problems?
What is the solution?

Comment: It's just that `OnlineCAT_Maint_TEST.dbo.ProductResource` does not exist in your database. Can you use `dbo.ProductResource`?

Comment: i have to modify in my sp? In MSSQL SP works fine...

Comment: I think so, yes. Are you working on different database?

Comment: no, it's same DB, 
i've modify my Sp, but same Problem:
{"Invalid object name 'OnlineCAT_Maint_TEST.ProductResource'."}

Comment: `OnlineCAT_Maint_TEST` is the database name, so it looks like the sproc not in that database.

Comment: no, ProductResource is a Table and exist

Comment: Is the database name `OnlineCAT_Maint_TEST`?

Comment: Yes, this DB parameters is ok... My controller is fine?

Comment: We're going round in circles. "Invalid object name" is a database error, so _there_ you should solve this. I said "use `dbo.ProductResource`" and you did `OnlineCAT_Maint_TEST.ProductResource`. Somewhere there is a database name mismatch.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I misunderstood what you said.
Now it Works!
Thanks man, you are a fxxking Genius,I have never done it without you! : )